# How to include dependency (method) of project A into project B using maven spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring boot application, My Project A(crux) has a Log generator class which I want to use in project B(bolt). I have included project A in the pom.xml of Project B but still its not able to find that.
package : com.test.sre.crux    & class : MyLogger.withField() in project B

pom.xml of B(bolt)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.sre.crux</groupId>
            <artifactId>Crux</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.apple.sre:bolt >-------------------------
[INFO] Building Bolt 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.test.sre.crux:Crux:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

pom.xml of A(crux)

```
    <groupId>com.test.sre</groupId>
    <artifactId>crux</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crux</name>
    <description>Repo for all the key metrics and usabilities</description>
```

I have also tried to include build path, please suggest.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group id and artifact id should be the same in both poms

```
<groupId>com.test.sre</groupId>
<artifactId>crux</artifactId>
```

Then, make sure you do a mvn install, so you have project A in your local maven repository.